# org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource] for bean

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

This is Spring MVC(5.2.6.RELEASE) and hibernate(5.4.17)  application. I'm creating this in Eclipse Photon IDE. I guess some JAR files has to be added but don't know what are  the JAR files. Also I don't know whether it is possible to create a  Spring MVC and Hibernate web application with hibernate.cfg.xml file instead of using spring-hibernate integration in applicationContext.xml.I'm using mysql workbench (8.0 CE) and the mysql connector is 8.0.20  Here is the error displayed :

```
un 03, 2020 10:18:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [studentDetails] in web application [/HibernateWithQuery] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:682)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1608)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:491)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1230)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getCandidateBeanNames(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:232)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$51/1849277142.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5180)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)

Jun 03, 2020 10:18:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jun 03, 2020 10:18:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [55,647] milliseconds
```

Here is spring-context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

       <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gavs" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

     <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/initialdb" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />

    </bean>

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.gavs.beans" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->

    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    </beans>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library for `c3p0 Connection Pooling` is missing. Add dependency to your build script.

**Gradle**

```
compile group: 'com.mchange', name: 'c3p0', version: '0.9.5.5'
```

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Or download [the jar from Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0/0.9.5.5) if you are not using any of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Minar, but when I run the code I got this exceptton :Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Comment: You are welcome Vishnu. Change `myDataSource` to `dataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc12"></context:component-scan>
  <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
  <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPoolDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/telusko"></property>
    <property name="user" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="12345678"></property>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"></property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"></property>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000"></property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springmvc12.alien"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager"/>
  
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/views/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```